# Java for loop with discrete values

Tags: java

I need a for loop that its limit could be exceeded after one ends(one of the limits), I like to declare the limit 9 and start traversing an array to index of 8 then start from 9 and take 9 more steps and so on,until I reach the end of the array, my tries reached to this point but I wonder if it works correctly:

```
int [] i={9,18,27,36,45,54,63,72,81};

for(int x:i){
   for(int j=0;j<x;j++)
      {}
     }
```

does the nested for loop going to change the `x` value after each complete cycle of the inner for loop or not?

Comment: look into the "foreach" function new with java 8

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question, you're unlikely to get help unless you make it clearer :)

Comment: Question and phrasing is really unclear..

Comment: does this nested for loop going to change the x value after each complete cycle of the inner for loop or not? `just use print statements`

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck i have a one dimensional array with 81 items which i want to check,you say an `if` condition on any 9 one of them,i asked if this code i've wrote could make it or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> then start from 9 and take 9 more steps

Your code doesn't behave as you want, since the inner loop always starts at 0.

There's no need to declare the `i` array. You can do it like this :

```
int start = 0;
for (int i = 9; i <= 81; i+=9) {
    for (int j = start; j < i; j++) {
    }
    start = i;
}
```

Or as phflack suggested :

```
for (int i = 9; i <= 81; i+=9) {
    for (int j = i - 9; j < i; j++) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a start variable, why not just use `int j = i - 9;`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = 9; i <= 81; i+=9) {
        for (int j = start; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        start = i;
        //System.out.print(start+" ");
    }
}
```

and you see:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 
18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 
36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 
45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 
54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 
63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 
72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
```

Another training for you:

```
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
```

and you can see:

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

> You can use two loop to print like matrix.